# How to add a new column with custom values, based on a WHERE clause from another table in PowerBi?

Tags: powerbi, data-science, powerquery, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am stuck while dynamically forming a new column based certain WHERE clause from another Table in PowerBi. To give more details, let's say I have a table with item numbers associated with a Customer Name. In another table, I have to add a new column, which will dynamically add the item numbers associated with a particular customer and append as a query parameter to a base url.

So, my first table looks like this:

[image]

The second table that I want is this:

[image]

The query parameter value in the URL, has to be dynamically based on a SELECT query with a WHERE clause and pick up the ItemNumbers using the Customer field which is common between both. So, how can this be done in PowerBi? Any help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: How do you want to use this new table (or URL column)? Put it to visualization?

Comment: yeah, add as a hyperlink in a tabular visualization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one table in my model "TableRol" if I want to summarize my Date as the string I can use CONCATENATEX;

[image]

```
URL = CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE("http:\\mysite.com\parametersHere\getitem?='",CONCATENATEX(VALUES('TableRol'[Date]), 'TableRol'[Date],";")),"'")
```

Comment: thanks, this looks good. Is it creating a new column or creating a new table with Class and URL as columns? Please excuse me if this is a very naïve question!

Comment: There is an issue with this, I am getting the same query values and not based on the particular class. In this example, I am getting all the date values as the query parameters for all the classes.

Comment: in my example, this is a new Measure, and its group by automatically based on columns that we add to Table Visualisation.

Comment: thanks! Changing it to measure instead of column actually solved the issue. I appreciate your help again :)